# Bulk insert documents in mongo with duplicate handling

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to insert documents in bulk in mongo, but some times I get a duplicate key exception and some of the documents which are not duplicates are not being inserted.

I found a solution where I can ignore all the duplicate insertions

```
BulkWriteOperation bulkWriteOperation =
            mongoTemplate.getCollection("collectionName").initializeUnorderedBulkOperation();
        BasicDBList dbList = new BasicDBList();
        dbList.addAll(documents);
        bulkWriteOperation.execute();
```

but following this solution , I have to check again in mongo which documents got inserted. Is there any way where I can insert all the non-duplicate documents and get an exception of some sort for the documents which are duplicates?

Comment: I suggest you find duplicates from the documents list and then insert the filtered list, that way you will have track of both inserted and duplicate records.

Comment: the only way we can know that is by accessing mongo . I dont want to access twice

Comment: What is there in `documents` object? You must have some lines apart from this, which stores data in `documents`.

Comment: Try upsert API.